# Overwhelming desire for life

Tags: meaning

I don't understand the meaning of below sentence. Can someone help me?

> An overwhelming desire for life made the hands clench the lifeline as if rigor mortis had already set in.

Reference: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rigor (quoted as a sample sentence, taken from Jenkins, Geoffrey,  *A DAYSTAR OF FEAR*, 2004)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rigor mortis](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rigor-mortis) is the stiffness of joints and muscular rigidity of a dead body.

To "clench the lifeline as if rigor mortis had already set in" is to clench it tightly or hard.   (The lifeline may well be metaphorical, though.)

Comment: Do you know meaning of this part "An overwhelming desire for life "?

Comment: Yes, it means an extremely strong or powerful desire to continue living.  A determination to avoid death.

Comment: excuse me, I don't understand "as if" and "set in".

Comment: "As if" means "as though" or "like if" or "similarly to a situation where" or "in the same way as if".  "Set in" means "occurred"/"taken place"/"affected his/her body".

Comment: @kris - If you are confused by "as if" and "set in", you really should mention that in your question. (The more details you can provide about what confuses you, the better answers you will get.)

Comment: Not from me.  I assume that people thought your question wasn't very clear.

Comment: @kris: not my downvote either, but your question wasn't specific enough. You did not say what it was that you did not understand. There are many things in that sentence which might prove troublesome for a learner, and those who would help you should not have to guess.